# SSRS Row grouping individual count by row groups

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have 3 table Survey_Questions,Answer and Question_category.
i want to view report like this

```
        QNo.    Yes No  NA
--------------------------------------------------------
category A  Q1  12  6   2
            Q2  34  7   1
            Q3  54  8   2
category B  Q1  23  3   3
            Q2  3   2   2
            Q3  32  2   1
category C  Q1  35  4   3
            Q2  54  2   3
            Q3  23  7   5
```

I have probleam with count. I use count function but it give result all tha row count not
row wise.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to play with the scope of your Count().  It is hard to make a specific suggestion without knowing your groups, but you can scope by group, region, or dataset.  Play around with it and hopefully you'll stumble on the right combo (that's what I always do - grin).

Good luck!

Comment: Thx for reply but how to handle the scope of count()?